# Como fazer busca no banco com três tipos de usuario?

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá estou fazendo um projeto da faculdade, é um projeto de site de estágios, ele tem que ser desenvolvido em Java WEB com banco de dados. Ele possui três tipo de usuário, o aluno, a empresa e o administrador. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de no momento de fazer o login eu não ter que fazer as buscas nas três tabelas.

Estava pensando em fazer um tabela usuário, no qual tem o email, a senha, o tipo dele(1- adm, 2- aluno...) e por fim um campo do id do usuário na sua respectiva tabela. Então faria a consulta na tabela usuário, e a partir do tipo dele, eu descobriria a tabela em que ele se encontra e com o id o achava.

Desta forma estou fazendo duas buscas. tem outra forma de fazer apenas com uma?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua classe de Usuario, defina o atributo "tipoUsuario" ou algo do tipo e ao instanciar o objeto defina o tipo dele buscando os valores em um Enum. Mais ou menos como:

```
public enum TipoUsuario {
    ADMIN, ALUNO, SISTEMA
}
```

Dai quando precisar checar o tipo de permissão pode consultar o tipo de permissão com um switch case por exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setNome("Banana");
    usuario.setTipoPermissao(TipoUsuario.ADMIN);

    switch (usuario.getTipoPermissao()) {
    case ADMIN:
        System.out.println("Usuario Administrador.");
        break;
    case ALUNO:
        System.out.println("Usuario Aluno.");
        break;
    case SISTEMA:
        System.out.println("Usuario Sistema.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Quem diabos é esse cara?");
        break;
    }
}
```

Isso tudo sem precisar mudar estrutura de tabelas, quando quiser mudar o tipo é só chamar o metodo usuario.setTipoPermissao e alterar para o tipo que quiser.

Comment: Isto pode ser uma alternativa aceitável se não houver campos específicos diferentes para cada tipo de usuário, ou se a quantidade de campos específicos for suficientemente pequena; para situações mais complexas, o uso de tabelas múltiplas pode vir a ser uma alternativa melhor. Como sempre, depende bastante da situação.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode realizar uma junção entre as tabelas no momento da consulta:

```
select *
from Usuario usu
left join Administrador adm on  adm.id   = usu.id
                            and usu.tipo = 1
left join Aluno alu on  alu.id   = usu.id
                    and usu.tipo = 2
```